# Configurable delays in Kafka docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, performance-testing

I've found a race condition in my code when consuming two distinct Kafka events that 99 times out of 100 arrive in the "correct" order. I've fixed the bug and I'd like to prove it.

For a one off I'm willing to put a `Thread.sleep()` on the consumer code, however, it'd be great to have a local kafka broker that I can configure to introduce delays for different criteria. Something similar to what Mountebank offers you for HTTP, if you've come across that.

I perform black-box testing by deploying a docker image of the application together with db/kafka/http server docker images as required. It'd be great to have a configurable docker Kafka image, do you know of one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Every main docker kafka image is configurable for any `server.properties` configuration.

But there is no such server-side setting for globally effecting every single partition of every single replica to make it longer to consume

If you want order, then you'd use one topic, with one partition, or interlock the consumer threads with `max.poll.records=1` and pause one consumer while the other runs (which will run really slow, most likely )

> have a local kafka broker

You don't need Docker for this, especially if you are using Spring's EmbeddedKafka tests

Comment: Maybe testing this aspect in an isolated replica of the real environment is too much to ask for. It would be ideal as it'd give me maximum confidence that nothing's been overlooked. One could also come up with many other similar test scenarios. It'll be interesting to see how the testing utils for Kafka develop. Thanks for the EmbeddedKafka suggestion.